# CANBUS module connector

Tags: pcb, connector, can

I am wondering if someone can suggest a mating connector they used for the MCP2515 CanBus Module (to connect J4). I can not find any datasheet or anything for it but I will be mounting the module to my PCB and then connecting it to my board. I have not ordered it, I am designing my board still.

[image: CANBUS Module]

Comment: Why not pick a MCU with built-in CAN controller instead of using these dinosaur parts? External CAN controllers went out of fashion during the previous millennium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J4: That is an unshrouded PCB pin strip. It does not have a specific mating connector. Because it is unshrouded, it can accept any single-row female plug with a 2.54 mm pitch. That includes:

- [Unshrouded rectangular plugs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078RRPRQZ) (a.k.a. "DuPont)
- [Individual crimp sockets](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XBZQDWM)
- [Prismatic plugs, latched or unlatched](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=prismatic_conn&&fl=0000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000-500-%7C2.54%7C%7C%7C%7C) (my site)

Or, for a reliable connection, solder wires directly to each pin (that's what I would do).

J2: That is a PCB terminal block. It does not have a mating connector. Instead, you place stripped wires into it and screw down the screws.

J1: place a [2.54 mm programming shunt / jumper](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HR8DGZO) on the two pins for the required 120 Ohm CAN bus termination.

Comment: Sometimes I hear these called a SIP or Single-Inline-Pin (header.)  So this would be a SIP 1x7, meaning one row of seven pins.

Comment: If you don't mind a bit of soldering, you could also remove the J4 pin header entirely and replace it with a connector receptacle on 0.1" centers, of which there are many.